# Problem while Installing React on Mac OS, using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I am getting following error when after

create-react-app react-app

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...npmjs.org/@webassembl'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kalpesh/.npm/_logs/2018-12-28T15_07_46_624Z-debug.log

Comment: try: npm cache clean --force

Comment: followed the steps here precisely worked fine: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-js-macos-setup/